# Делегаты. Windows Forms. Вопрос от новичка

Tags: c#, winforms, события, делегаты

У меня такой вопрос: почему невозможно совершить данное преобразование:

```
using System;

namespace Learn_Words_WF_Menus
{
    public delegate void Action(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Learn_Words_WF_Menus
{
    public class EMPTY : ControlMenu
    {
        Button Back_Button;

        public EMPTY(Form form, Action backButton_Click) : base(form)
        {
            Set_Actions(backButton_Click);
        }

        private void Set_Actions(Action backButton_Click)
        {
            Back_Button.Click += backButton_Click; // вот тут выдает ошибку 
            //Ошибка CS0029 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип
            //"Learn_Words_WF_Menus.Action" в "System.EventHandler"
        }
    }
}
```

Но можно сделать сделать так:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Learn_Words_WF_Menus
{
    public class EMPTY : ControlMenu
    {
        Button Back_Button;

        public EMPTY(Form form, Action backButton_Click) : base(form)
        {
            Set_Actions(backButton_Click);
        }

        private void Set_Actions(Action backButton_Click)
        {
            Back_Button.Click += Click;
        }
        
        private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Что я делаю неправильно или чего я не понимаю? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Сигнатуры у функций видимо разные, вот и не может преобразовать

Comment: Не называйте лелегат Action, чтобы избежать конфликта с System.Action

Comment: Да, действительно, заметил что происходит такой конфликт. Получается, что у меня было две ошибки сразу. 1. Я, по не знанию, создал свой делегат который конфликтовал с другим системным классом, вместо того чтобы просто использовать System.EventHandler. 2. Я неправильно прикреплял делегат к событию. И вот второй пункт я считаю стоит оставить. Вдруг кто еще наткнется на такую проблему. Если вы можете порекомендовать мне, как мне можно отредактировать данный пост, чтобы сохранить именно решение второй проблемы, то буду благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

В общем. Нашел решение. Состоит оно в том что нужно писать так:

```
using System;

namespace Learn_Words_WF_Menus
{
    public delegate void Action(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Learn_Words_WF_Menus
{
    public class EMPTY : ControlMenu
    {
        Button Back_Button;

        public EMPTY(Form form, Action backButton_Click) : base(form)
        {
            Set_Actions(backButton_Click);
        }

        private void Set_Actions(Action backButton_Click)
        {
            Back_Button.Click += backButton_Click.Invoke; // вот решение
        }
    }
}
```

Почему так? Не знаю. Но это работает. Если кто-то знает, буду благодарен за объяснение. На этом все. Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: А зачем здесь вообще какой-то свой тип делегата, если можно использовать EventHandler?

Comment: К сожалению, я о нем не знал. Теперь знаю. Спасибо